# How to change the page title of product list pages

Tags: magento-1, product-list, eav, custom-attributes

I have a list of titles I want to overwrite the default page title on multiple product list pages with (title tag in the html head). But not on the product view page, only on the 'product list' page.

I tried creating a new custom attribute 'productlist_pagetitle' which would contain the new title. In template/page/html/head.phtml I would then use the title taken from the attribute to write it to the title tag.

However I am confused about a few things.

- as far as I understand I can use the attribute as a meta field, but it is attached to a product. is there a way to link the attribute to 'product list' pages?
- where / how can I actually enter my data (the new titles)?
- how I can access the value of the attribute?

Sorry, I'm new to Magento and their EAV model. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: by product list you meant category pages?

Answer (score 0):

why not to set category page title on category edit page:

[image]